# Method Illuminate\Http\Request::validated does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, validation

i tried use validation system but give me error `Method Illuminate\Http\Request::validated does not exist`.

**fileController.php**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'titre' => ['bail','required_without:titre', 'string','min:3', 'max:255'],
                'name' => ['bail','required_without:name', 'string','min:3', 'max:255'],
                 ]);
          $file= new File($request->validated());
          $file->save();
            return Redirect::to("/")
            ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no `validated` method on `Illuminate\Http\Request`. That method is only on FormRequests (because you are not the one who calls the `validate` method on the FormRequest, it is done for you, and there needs to be a way to get that data).

The `validate` method you are calling on your controller returns the validated data.

```
$validated = $this->validate(...):
```

Answer (score 3):

This is another way from @lagbox's answer, in the Laravel's [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#working-with-validated-input) docs you will see this.

```
$validated = $request->validated();
 
$validated = $validator->validated();
```

You can try the approach below.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);

$validated = $validator->validated();
```